# Get the difference between 2 arrays based on value?

Tags: php

array 1:

```
 array(
     0  => 34345,
     1 => 56465,
     2 => 76575
      )
```

array 2:

```
  array(
     0  => 34345,
     1 => 454354,
     2 => 76465
      )
```

How can I get rid of the repeating values in both arrays? Note: array 1 has 9 pairs while array 2 have 160 pairs.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get as a result? What did you try to accomplish that? Do you have some code?

Comment: @Patrick basically I have 2 arrays of records and I want to get rid of the repeating values from 1 to 2nd array

Answer (score 0):

you can get the difference between two array using this php function : array_diff($array1,$array2)

Comment: doesnt that just compare the keys?

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all the items in `$array2` that share the same value as any item in `$array1`.

```
foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if ($keys = array_keys($array2, $value)) {
        foreach($keys as $key) {
            unset($array2[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```